# Selecting sub-arrays using vector combination

Tags: r, vector

The following statement makes an array:

```
x = array(data = 1:6, dim = c(2,3))
```

which looks like:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6
```

Okay, I understood this, but what does the following statement mean:

```
x[c(1,2), c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)]
```

It outputs:

```
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    3
 [2,]    2    4
```

What is actually happening?

Comment: You can see which indices are being selected with `which`. Since `which(c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE))` is `c(1,2)`, columns 1 and 2 are being selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A matrix is indexed as follows: `matrix[rows, columns]`. What you are doing is telling it to:
Take rows 1 and 2 (`c(1, 2)`) and 
take the first and second columns (`TRUE, TRUE, FALSE`), hence the result

```
x[c(1,2), c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    3
#[2,]    2    4
```

If you change the sequence of your logical expression to `TRUE, FALSE, TRUE`, then you are grabbing the first and third columns, i.e.

```
x[c(1,2), c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    5
#[2,]    2    6
```

Comment: As a complement, in R you can provide indices as numeric, boolean, and even sometimes character. So you can also provide here a vector of Booleans for rows and numeric for columns for instance. Note that vectors of Booleans will be recycled, so in your example, `c(TRUE,FALSE)` would give the same output as  `c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE)`